# Apache Spark Re-partitioning / Bucketing Best Practice to Avoid Skewed Data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am focusing on bucketing and re-partitioning dataframe as means of grouping data together in order to speed up later processing.

With bucketing, the aim is to split the data into a fixed number of "buckets" over some set of columns. The objective is split partitioned data into an equal set of buckets.

As I'm sure you've gathered that the overall objective is to use this method to prevent data skew.

The following is a step-by-step procedure that I have adopted to implement bucketing.

Please note, I'm using Spark SQL as opposed to PySpark, but the principles are the same. For example, I'm using the function called NTILE to bucket the data. This function is taken from typical T-SQL.

Anyway, here we go:

I have the following two DataFrames

```
df_table1 = spark.read.csv("/tamingskew/table1/", header=True)
df_table2 = spark.read.csv("/tamingskew/table2/", header=True)
```

Apache Spark takes a the dataframe and creates the a single partition for each, as shown with the following code:

```
df_table1.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

1

I then create two tables to execute the queries on to generate the bucketted data:

```
df_table1.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
df_table2.createOrReplaceTempView("t2")
```

Now, going to do some bucketing and repartitioning on the first table 't1'

```
df_pt1 = spark.sql("""SELECT
  t1.*
 ,NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY t1.registration) AS newpart1
FROM t1
ORDER BY newpart1 DESC
""").repartition(8, col("newpart1"))
```

As you can see from the above, I have bucketed the data into 8 buckets and repartitioned the data in 8 partitions based on the bucketed data 'newpart1'

I then execute the following code to view what the partitioned data looks like

```
print("Number of partitions: {}".format(df_pt1.rdd.getNumPartitions())) 
print('Partitioning distribution: '+ str(df_pt1.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()))
```

It looks like the following:

```
Number of partitions: 8
Partitioning distribution: [0, 1250, 1250, 3750, 0, 0, 2500, 1250]
```

The above output isn't ideal, because as you can see there are 3 partitions don't have any data at all.

I then create a table from the above bucketted dataframe to use on my final query:

```
df_pt1.createOrReplaceTempView('t11')
```

I then do exactly the same for table2 (won't go into all the detail again)

```
df_pt2 = spark.sql("""SELECT
  t2.*
 ,NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY t2.sale_price) AS newpart2
FROM t2
ORDER BY newpart2 DESC
""").repartition(8, col("newpart2"))


print("Number of partitions: {}".format(df_pt2.rdd.getNumPartitions())) 
print('Partitioning distribution: '+ str(df_pt2.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()))

Number of partitions: 8
Partitioning distribution: [0, 12500, 12500, 37500, 0, 0, 25000, 12500]

df_pt2.createOrReplaceTempView('t22')
```

And the final query is as follows:

```
querywithgroups = spark.sql("""SELECT
  t11.registration
 ,AVG(t22.sale_price) AS average_price
FROM t11
INNER JOIN t22
  ON t11.make = t22.make
    AND t11.model = t22.model
WHERE ABS(t22.engine_size - t11.engine_size) <= 0.1
GROUP BY t11.registration
        ,t11.newpart1
        ,t22.newpart2
""")
```

This provides the following split partitiions:

```
Number of partitions: 8
Partitioning distribution: [0, 10000, 10000, 30000, 0, 0, 20000, 10000]
```

My question is this: Is there a better way of using bucketing to partition data in order speed up queries?
Can the above be improved upon.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I understand, your main process starts by a `JOIN` on `make` and `model`, so Spark will (to my admitedly limited knowledge) shuffle your data using those columns to begin with. Which defeats any partionning that was done before - it will just be pure waste. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @GPI, thanks for reaching out. I honestly don't know the answer. I'm hoping that someone from SE will provide some interesting suggestions